# Pressure Applied by Sphere Embedded in Elastic Medium

Tags: forces, pressure, elasticity

Consider a sphere embedded inside of an infinite elastic and isotropic medium. If a force $F$ is applied to the ball from a distance (e.g. via a magnetic field), then the ball will in turn apply a force to the surrounding medium. This force acts in 1 direction only (let's say the $z$ direction).

How do I calculate the pressure at the ball medium interface?

I know that the pressure $p=F/A$, but my understanding is that only the component of the force normal to the surface of the sphere (i.e. parallel to the area vector at each point) will contribute to the pressure. I'm thinking that I need to some how integrate the perpendicular component of the force over the surface area of the sphere. (Or maybe just half the surface area, since only one half of the sphere will be "pushing on" the elastic medium. Can someone help me understand how to set up this integral?

Comment: See Lin et al., "Force-displacement relationships for spherical inclusions in finite elastic media," *Journal of Applied Physics* 97 (2005) and the references within. Also see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.08823.pdf).

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thank you for suggesting those papers. In my case though, I already know what the applied force and resulting displacements are analytically, and I'm just trying to take it one step further to calculate pressure

Comment: Could you clarify what information you have already and what you mean by "pressure"? It's not clear whether the inclusion is rigid or elastic, for example, and whether slip is allowed at the interface. Also, there's generally no single pressure in these types of problems; a complex stress state arises in both the inclusion and the medium. Are you looking for the maximum stress at the leading edge of the sphere? What's the general problem you're trying to solve?